# How to validate two or more mobile numbers in one field, when using jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery-validate, validation

I am using [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate client forms. In one field i need to accept two or more country mobile number which should be a valid mobile number. Say if i need to accept Indian mobile number or US mobile number. How shall i validate both in one field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the depends field.

```
$("#element").validate({
   rules: {
       phone: {
         depends: function(element) {
           if('behavestoA' || 'behavestoB'){ return true }else{ return false }
         }
       }
   }
   messages: {
       phone: "Please format your phone number correctly"
   }
})
```

in behavestoA or behavestoB you of course then have to put your conditions.

Good luck!